# How do I use IPython as my Emacs Python interpreter?

Tags: python, macos, configuration, emacs, ipython

I'm running Emacs 22.1.1 and IPython 0.9.1 on OS X and I'd like to be able to run lines/methods/snippets of Python code from my current buffer on demand inside an IPython interpreter.

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 4):

also ipython wont load with the official python.el being used with emacs 23.1.1

Answer (score 4):

This version of emacs for mac:

http://emacsformacosx.com

comes with package.el pre-installed. This allows you to automatically install emacs packages. There is a package called ein:

http://tkf.github.io/emacs-ipython-notebook/

which makes it easy to interact with ipython from emacs (including notebooks).

However, as of version 24.3 of the emacs above, ein is not in the default package repository. If you add more repositories, as per:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA

i.e., add this to your ~/.emacs file:

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                     ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                     ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
```

then call

```
M-x package-refresh-contents
```

you will now be able to add ein with:

```
M-x package-install <ret> ein
```

alas the MELPA version of ein does not work with ipython > 1.x so if you are using ipython 2.x,  you need a newer build of ein:

https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook/issues/137

so clone that:

```
git clone https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook.git
```

copy the lisp sub directory somewhere sensible:

```
cp -r emacs-ipython-notebook/lisp ~/.emacs.d/einv2
```

then add it to your emacs load path and load it, by adding this to your ~/.emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/einv2")
  (require 'ein)
```

finally, get rid of the old ein, which will leave the dependencies in place:

```
M-x package-list-packages
```

scroll to ein in the package list, then:

```
M-x package-menu-mark-delete
M-x package-menu-execute
```

Restart emacs and you can connect to your ipython notebook server:

```
M-x ein:notebooklist-open
```

Answer (score 0):

python-mode.el supports IPython natively.

Just make sure shebang doesn't point to another interpreter.

In this case:

- either call a command with ending "-ipython", which will override shebang
- customize "ipython" as default interpreter and set `py-force-py-shell-name-p'. This might be done also via menu
  Python/.../Switches